# Objective C++, how to use runloop in background thread?

Tags: c++, objective-c, multithreading, core-bluetooth, nsrunloop

**Big edit**: I think the question can be simplified to--how can I run corebluetooth and initialize CBCentralManager in background thread? Thank you!

I am making an an objective c++ application with CoreBluetooth that runs through the commandline, so the object C portion needs the runloop to be explicitly called [see [this]](https://gist.github.com/cmittendorf/2c6eefc6dd128b323428). CoreBluetooth requires there to be an active runloop so callbacks are performed. The code below makes a call to the runloop in the beginning of the program to make everything work:

**implementation.mm**

```
// inside init method

// initialize bluetooth manager, must initialize before the runloop
self.centralManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil];
// start run loop
NSRunLoop *runLoop = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
            while(([runLoop runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]]))
            {}
```

and I can make async calls from my c++ main method:

**main.cpp**

```
int main() {

    std::thread worker(do_cpp_things); // c++ things in background thread
    run_objective_c_code(); // call objective c code using main thread
}
```

However with this approach, my c++ portion must be run in the background thread. and the objective C application is in the main thread which is opposite to what I want. So I tried to make a new thread in the objective C file then call the current run loop of the thread:

**implementation.mm**

```
// start a new thread
-(void)startThread {
    NSThread *A = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(runTheLoop) object:nil]; //create thread A
    [A start];
}

// call runloop while in new thread
-(void) runTheLoop {
    // Commenting out initialization for the sake of simplicity before it terminates when trying to initialize the manager in this example
    // self.centralManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil]; 


    NSRunLoop *runLoop = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop]; 
    // TERMINATES HERE
    while(([runLoop runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]]))
    {} 


}
```

But this just terminates early. Not sure if there is something fundamentally wrong with my approach. Again--I want to run my objective-C code in the background thread with an active runloop and my c++ code in the main thread.

Thanks!

**Actually wait, this solution doesn't properly make a runloop in background thread**:

One of my problems is getting a runloop to run in a background thread.
**main.cpp**

```
int main() {
  std::thread worker(run_cpp_in_thread);

}
```

**implementation.mm**
// somewhere in init method

```
NSRunLoop *runLoop = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
[runLoop run];
```

Now the problem is that CoreBluetooth is exiting immediately after powered on the central manager. Seems like something to do with the framework and threading.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are asking c++ to run in thread which is working in background.
Instead, just push C function to run in background

```
int main() {

    std::thread worker(run_objective c function); // objective c in background thread
   do_cpp_things; // call c++ things code using main thread
}
```

You still need to handle join properly otherwise can make your application unresponsive/crash

Comment: Thanks for the response! This is much simpler than what I was doing with creating the thread in the objective c code. However, the runloop call is still not working.

Comment: If you post runloop call and highlight the problem and what to want to achieve, it will be easier to respond

Comment: the runloop call is in implementation.mm under -(void) runTheLoop(). Again, I want to call an infinitely running runloop in a background thread so I can run Corebluetooth in the background thread. Even if I remove corebluetooth from the system and add a timer to the runloop to keep it alive, having a runloop in the background thread doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Okay I got the runloop working in the background thread, now I think there is something funky going on with corebluetooth not liking background threads, will update question with how I got it working